# Add Columns to a Pandas Dataframe with dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have two dictionaries:

```
 
Latitud = {'Cundinamarca': 4.6 , 'Norte de Santander': 7.9, 'Antioquia': 6.2} 

Longitud = {'Cundinamarca': -74.1 , 'Norte de Santander': -72.5, 'Antioquia': -75.5}
```

and I have tried to create 2 new columns in a Dataframe, taking in account the 'Departamento' column, with this code:

```
df['Latitud'] = df['Departamento'].map(Latitud) 

df['Longitud'] = df['Departamento'].map(Longitud)
```

But I have this:

```
Departamento , Municipio , Latitud , Longitud

Cundinamarca , Bogota    , Nan     , Nan

Cundinamarca , Bogota    , Nan     , Nan

Norte de Santander , Cúcuta    , Nan     , Nan

Antioquia    , Medellín    , Nan     , Nan
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: Hi @NiengLee_, can you please explain in a little more detail on what you are trying to achieve. Thank You for sharing the code and output. To help you a bit, please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be case-insensitive problems, We could try map with lowercase:

```
df['Latitud'] = df['Departamento'].str.lower().map({k.lower() : v 
                                                    for k,  v in Latitud.items()})
```

and the same for `Longitud`

May be necessary replace blanks:

```
df['Latitud'] = (df['Departamento'].str.lower()
                                   .str.replace(' ', '').map({k.lower() : v                                                      
                                                             for k,  v in Latitud.items()})
                 )
```

Comment: try replace blanks spaces : `df['Latitud'] = df['Departamento'].str.lower().str.replace(' ', '').map({k.lower() : v 
                                                    for k,  v in Latitud.items()})`